# Let Rails trigger update of nginx config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I'm currently adding user domains to my Rails application. Which means they can use example.com to reach their profile page on my Rails app. I've already implemented this on the Rails side but what's missing is the Nginx side.

How can the Rails app somehow update the Nginx config (add/remove specific domain) and let Nginx reload the config to handle requests from these domains?

Comment: How have you implemented it in Rails?

Comment: Well, it checks for the domain in the request and redirects to the user's profile page accordingly. All I need now is let Nginx know about these domains.

Comment: Nginx doesnt care about the domains, it is listening for requests on a specific ip:port combo. If you have more than 1 server block then the first one in your config will be used as a catch all for any domains not specified in a `server_name` directive, you can override this behaviour by adding `default_server` to the `listen` directive of any other server block to make that the catch all.

Comment: True, much better 